# Exporting the differences in xlxs sheet in desired cells using R

Tags: r

I've to compare multiple files (Prod1, Beta1, Prod2, Beta2.. etc) and export the differences in an excel sheet if any. That should be in separate cells (Column C). I'm trying with below code `library(xlsx)` I can store the data only in the 1st cell.

```
library(xlsx)
for(i in 1:No_of_files){

  prod_file_res_name <- sprintf("R/Results/F_Query_Prod_%s.txt", i)
  beta_file_res_name <- sprintf("R/Results/F_Query_Beta_%s.txt", i)

  if (file.exists(prod_file_res_name) && file.exists(beta_file_res_name))
  {
    res <- tools::Rdiff(prod_file_res_name, beta_file_res_name, Log = TRUE)

    if(res[2] != "character(0)"){

    write.xlsx(toString(res[2]), file = "C:/R/diff.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", col.names = FALSE, row.names =FALSE, append = TRUE)

    }

    else{
  com <- "No Difference found"
  write.xlsx(com, file = "C:/R/diff.xlsx", sheetName = "ExtractFormulaHistory", col.names = FALSE, row.names =FALSE, append = TRUE)
    }
  }
  else {
    print("File doesnt exist")
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me to save the difference in column 5 but different rows(example: 1 to X no of files)? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a `tibble`, or `list` to hold you output and then in the last step of your code output it to Excel using the `xlsx` library.

Alternatively, you could use the `writeWorksheet`  from  `XLConnect` package to write to an Excel file as you work out the differences.

From documentation of the `XLConnect` package:

```
# Load workbook (create if not existing)
wb <- loadWorkbook("writeWorksheet.xlsx", create = TRUE)

# Create a worksheet called 'CO2'
createSheet(wb, name = "CO2")

# Write built-in data set 'CO2' to the worksheet created above;
# offset from the top left corner and with default header = TRUE
writeWorksheet(wb, CO2, sheet = "CO2", startRow = 4, startCol = 2)

# Save workbook (this actually writes the file to disk)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```